# making a image a zoom in and out button

Tags: jquery, image, button, zooming

i have two images of a plus and a minus. i want to make those images into a zom in and zoom out button for another image.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="upperMall" >
        <img alt="" height="972" src="images/UpperMall.png" width="1728">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="zoom">
    <img alt="" height="75" src="images/btnMinus.png" width="75">
    <img alt="" height="75" src="images/btnplus.png" width="75">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sorry i worked it out.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#zoom-in').click(function () {
        $('#pic').width($('#pic').width()*1.2)
        $('#pic').height($('#pic').height()*1.2)

    })
        $('#zoom-out').click(function () {
        $('#pic').width($('#pic').width()/1.2)
        $('#pic').height($('#pic').height()/1.2)

    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me out, just what I was looking for. Nice stuff :)